# No such method issue with websockets and spring 4 and tomcat 7

Tags: spring, tomcat7, sockjs, spring-websocket

Hi im getting the following issue with websockets and spring 4 and tomcat 7. I deployed the application on tomcat and when i try to get the websocket to work i get the following error.

Anyone got any ideas as to where my conflict is, i know its a maven dependency issue been trawling through the hierarchy...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession.getAttributes()Ljava/util/Map;
    at com.ingg.virgo.connection.sockjs.messagehandler.VirgoSockJSTextWebSocketHandler.handleTextMessage(VirgoSockJSTextWebSocketHandler.java:84) ~[VirgoSockJSTextWebSocketHandler.class:na]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.AbstractWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(AbstractWebSocketHandler.java:43) [spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.java:84) ~[spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:59) ~[spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:55) ~[spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:69) ~[spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.delegateMessages(AbstractSockJsSession.java:153) [spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession.handleMessage(WebSocketServerSockJsSession.java:154) [spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.SockJsWebSocketHandler.handleTextMessage(SockJsWebSocketHandler.java:77) [spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.AbstractWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(AbstractWebSocketHandler.java:43) [spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.handleTextMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:112) [spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.access$000(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:42) [spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:82) [spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:79) [spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageText(WsFrameBase.java:369) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataText(WsFrameBase.java:468) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:272) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:116) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:54) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:192) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:178) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:92) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:601) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_03]
```

Comment: then could you show your maven dependencies configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Found issue was to do with servlet-api not being at 3.1